# How to delete lines from a file if they exceed x number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I do something like this?

```
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt') as f:
    list = f.readlines()
for line in list:
    if line: #has more than x characters
        delete line
```

Comment: format your code properly use code formatter

Comment: To clarify: do you want to change the original file or create another file without the long strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is reasonably small, the easiest way is to read it all in, filter, then write it all out.

```py
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt')  as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Keep lines <= 10 chars long with a list comprehension
filtered_lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 10]

# Do what you like with the lines, e.g. write them out into another file:
with open(r'C:\filtered_list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in filtered_lines:
        f.write(line)
```

If you want to stream the matching lines into another file, that's even easier:

```py
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt') as in_file, open(r'C:\filtered_list.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if len(line) <= 10:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Sure. Added example about streaming them into another file.

Comment: Why do you use `print(line, file=out_file)` instead of  `out_file.write(line + "\n")`?

Comment: @DYZ Why not? Besides, as a micro-optimization, I'd imagine the builtin handles concatenating the end-of-line character better than allocating a new string on the Python side.

Comment: Each `line` already has a trailing newline; `print`ing it will add a second.

Comment: I always forget whether or not iterating lines have a trailing newline :D Fixed...

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file line by line, write the line in a new file if it pass the constrain (abandon other lines). For large files, its so efficient in terms of memory usage:

```
with open('file_r.txt', 'r') as file_r, open('file_w.txt', 'w') as file_w:
    thresh = 3
    for line in file_r:
        if len(line) < thresh:
            file_w.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (I do `3` as an example):

```
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt')  as f:
    l = [i for i in f if len(i) > 3]
```

I renamed `list` to `l` since `list` is a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

first save the lines in a list which will not  be deleted by reading one by one:

```
the_list = []
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        #print(len(line))
        if (len(line)) < 50:#here I used 50 charecters
            the_list.append(line)
```

then write the list into your file:

```
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in the_list:
        f.write(line)
```

if you don't want to use a list or the file is too big then try:

```
with open(r'C:\some_list.txt', "r") as f, open('new.txt', 'a') as fw:
    for line in f:
        if (len(line)) < 50:
            fw.write(line)
```

replace  output.txt according to your need. Above  code will read line by line from  some_list.txt and then write in 'output.txt' if the line has less than 50 characters

Comment: If you use `with open()` there is no need to `close()` - the context manager does that for you.

Comment: @tripleee ,  thanks for the info, I have edited the answer

Comment: Reopening the destination file repeatedly in append mode is inefficient and weird.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, it could be done like this:

```
# fname : file name
# x : number of characters or length
def delete_lines(fname = 'test.txt', x = 8):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(fname, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) <= x:            
                f.write(line)

delete_lines()
```

Certainly, there are better ways of doing this.